# What is the plain Javascript equivalent of calling jQuery.on()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a JQuery-free app. Can someone please provide the raw JS equivalent to this JQuery code:

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
  // do something...
})
```

Thanks,
Doug

Comment: Just open the source of the jQuery `on` method and you will know.

Comment: This is a bootstrap jQuery plugin, no? Are you sure you can use it without jQuery?

Comment: `'hidden.bs.modal'` is an event?

Comment: Do you understand what the existing code means? Break it down, take each part (I count at least 4 distinct tasks there) separately.

Comment: @SamCreamer It's a custom event that the Bootstrap 3 library triggers, yes

Comment: Wow, a crowd. Yes, this is one of the handful of callbacks from the Bootstrap modal JS component. Ismail, why would I not be able to use the JS equivalent? SamCreamer, what Ian said. Quentin, I prefer to use the StackOverflow hive mind.

Comment: Note, I am an iOS dev new to JS. I'm in a hurry and need to get this sorted. Cheers.

Comment: Can someone please explain to me why this was downvoted so much? Seems like a perfectly valid question to me

Comment: Haters gonna hate. Cheers SamCreamer.

Comment: "being in a hurry" is not an excuse for lack of basic research. All of our time is worth something. A simple Google search gives multiple results providing (oftentimes clearer) answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.querySelector("#myModal").addEventListener("hidden.bs.modal", function(e) {});`
or
`document.getElementById("myModal").addEventListener("hidden.bs.modal", function(e) {});`